# Replace parts of string in sqlite3

Tags: python, replace, sqlite, replicate

I want to replace parts information in my strings.

> e.g. From `+1-2024561111` To `+1-202***1111`

I found a query `REPLICATE` which could achieve what I want. However, it seems not available in sqlite3.

And the `REPLACE` in sqlite can only replace some certain strings. What I need is to replace strings in **certain positions**. One alphabet replaces one '*' ; they need to have the same length after replacing.

Even the Excel can do this easily by using `REPLACE(old_text, start_num, num_chars, new_text)`. Is there any way to solve this? BTW, I'm using sqlite3 in python. The solution written in python is also acceptable.

Comment: So different substrings are to be handled differently? Why can't you use `substr()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using substr and replace in sqlite

I finally use `substr(x,y,z)` to get the first `z` chars from `y`(I set 1 to get start at the beginning of the original string).

Then use `||` to connect two strings. It's a little different with the answer provided by @Hugh Bothwell.

After `||`, I use `replace(substr(quote(zeroblob((Y + 1) / 2)), 3, Y), '0', '*')` to fill the string to `length Y`. It's a little hard to understand at the beginning.[This website](http://blog.jooq.org/2012/07/19/funky-string-function-simulation-in-sqlite/) has more information for you.

I need my string to be masked after 5th chars, so I don't need to append anything behind the `replace` statement. If you need, just add another `||` and use `substr()`.

> In short, what I did is: `+1-2024561111` (original string)
>
> - substr()  ➜ `+1-202456`
> - `||` ➜ to append another string
> - the `replace` statement ➜ to fill string to a certain length ➜ `+1-202456****`

### Another solution: in python

It's a normal statement to print database in [sqlite3 in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#) like this:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM stocks ORDER BY price'):
        print row
```

I add a `if-else` statement and use [ljust](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/ljust.html) to do what I want.

It's a sample below:

```
-- row[0]: the first filed in table, here means numbers

    if len(row[0])>=9:
            newNum=row[0][0:10].ljust(len(row[0]),'*')
                        #^^^^^^ to get first 9 chars in row[0]

    # ljust fill in '*' from 10th char to the length of row[0]

    print(newNum) # use newNum instead of row[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
REPLACE(old_text, start_num, num_chars, new_text)
```

should be identical to

```
SUBSTR(old_str, 1, start_num - 1) || new_text || SUBSTR(old_str, start_num + LENGTH(new_text))
```